# Why does @AfterSuit doesnt run without alwaysRun=true?

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, testng

I have the below `@AfterSuit` method. If I remove **alwaysRun=true**, TestNG is not executing it.

```
@AfterSuite(alwaysRun=true)
public void finishsuit()
{
    System.out.println("completed suit");
}
```

I checked the documentation for alwaysRun and it says:

> For after methods (afterSuite, afterClass, ...): If set to true, this
>   configuration method will be run even if one or more methods invoked
>   previously failed or was skipped.

This is what i understood : If any of the `@Test` method defined inside any of the classes specified in any of the `<test>` belonging to the current suit fails, then `@AfterSuit` wont be executed unless we specify `alwaysRun=true`.

But in my case none of the `@Test` are failing. And still my `@AfterSuite` is not executing without `alwaysRun=true`

Comment: @BeforeMethod and similar annotated methods count here as well. Sure that no error occurred? Please share your code.

Comment: I was assuming it only counts the test methods. I checked all the other methods aswell and found the issue. One of my '@AfterTest method was failing because i had given invalid arguments. Fixed that and now my '@AfterSuit is working fine without alwaysRun. Thank you! Will close this question.

Comment: Is this property only applicable to AfterSuit?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably running your test methods in groups and AfterSuite is not part of any group, that's why you need the `alwaysRun=true`.

But because I see you are a little bit confused about alwaysRun behavior, I'll proceed to explain...

**For @BeforeXXXX methods**, alwaysRun needs to be assigned if you want to run the method despite it doesn't belong to the group you are running.
Eg.

```
public class TestConfig {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        doSomething();
    }
    
}

public class TestClassA extends TestConfig {

    @Test(groups = { "groupA" })
    public void testA() {
        doTest();
    }

}
```

In this case, if we run group 'groupA', the @BeforeSuite method is not part of the group we are executing, **unless** we specify `alwaysRun = true`.

**The same applies for @AfterXXXX methods**, plus they need alwaysRun=true if you want to run them despite their @Before counterpart has failed or any depending methods. For example:

```
public class TestClassA {
    
    @BeforeSuite( groups = { "testA" })
    public void beforeSuite() {
        doSomethingBefore();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    
    @Test( groups = { "testA" })
    public void testA() {
        doTest();
    }
    
    @AfterSuite( groups = { "testA" })
    public void afterSuite() {
        doSomethingAfter();
    }
    
}
```

Now, **@AfterSuite** method won't run because it's counterpart **@BeforeSuite** has failed. the same will apply if **@AfterSuite** is on a class where a **@BeforeClass** had failed. But if we add `alwaysRun=true` testng will ignore any previous failure and proceed anyway.

NONE OF THIS APPLIES TO **@TEST** METHODS. @BeforeXXXX and @AfterXXXX methods will run ignoring any @Test results UNLESS you specify a [test dependency](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods).

**Finally, alwaysRun in @Test methods will act in similar way as `ignoreMissingDependencies=true`.** For example:

```
@Test
public void testA() {
    doTestA();
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { testA }))
public void testB() {
    doTestB();
}
```

Again, in this case testB won't run because it depends on @TestA, unless we assign alwaysRun=true (or ignoreMissingDependencies=true).

Answer (score 0):

If you run it as a TestNG class, only  @BeforeSuite method get picked even though @AfterSuite(alwaysRun=true) 
 However if you run it as a Testsuite via testplan.xml ,@AfterSuite method get picked directly and no need to have alwaysRun=true

Both BeforeSuite and AfterSuite, are work in **optimal** way if you run it as a test suite via xml rather than run it directly as a TestNG class. Since those are meant to be suite level annotations

Example - If I run below code as a class , the output will don't have the afterSuite method.

```
public class TestngExamples {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void initation() {
        System.out.println("Before suite is ran ");
    }


    @Test
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello world method");
    }
    @Test
    public void demo() {
        System.out.println("demo method");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("After suite is ran ");
    }

}
```

However If I run it as a Test suite xml it will print the Aftersuite method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.webdriver.blogs.TestngExamples"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Sample output-
Before suite is ran 
demo method
Hello world method
After suite is ran

Answer (score 0):

**For after methods (afterSuite, afterClass, ...): If set to true, this configuration method will be run even if one or more methods invoked previously failed or was skipped.**

Methods here means all the @test methods and the all the other annotated methods aswell. in my case i was using invalid arguments to my @AfterTest function, causing it to fail. That was why my @BeforeTest was not working without alwaysRun

Comment: No, it doesn't include Test methods. You can try this by creating a class with a number of tests and force an error in one of them, AfterXXXX will still run. This is done in case you need to close a connection that you have opened or any situation of the sort.